# Color Palette Algorithm to output a grid of colors from red'ish to blue'ish

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx, rgb, color-picker

As you see here http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm The colors go from red to blue and from dark to white in a algorithmic pattern. How would you code that in a basic loop? Im making this for JavaFX training!

Here is the basic structure I have so far with Random Colors, should be replaced with an algorithm:

```
    for(int x = 0;x<12;x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y< 10; y++) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int r = random.nextInt(256);
            int g = random.nextInt(256);
            int b = random.nextInt(256);

            Label label = new Label();
            label.setPrefSize(30,30);
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")");
            colorPane.add(label, x,y);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The color palette you see in the link is an HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value) color palette.  Attempting to reproduce it using RGB (Red, Green, Blue) is going to lead to some headaches.

Example (untested) of HSV implementation:

```
int h = 0;
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        int s = 10 * y;
        int b = 10 * x;

        Label label = new Label();
        label.setPrefSize(30,30);
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: hsb(" + h + "," + s + "%," + b + "%)");
        colorPane.add(label, x,y);
    }
}
```

Note that Java calls it HSB (Hue, Saturation, Brightness) instead of HSV for some reason (probably because "Value" is extremely non-descriptive).  Check out the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) (looking at the static `hsb(double h, double s, double b)` method) for an in-code reference, and the [CSS guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) for defining in CSS (like we're doing here).

Answer (score 1):

Note I'd recommend using `Rectangle`s instead of `Label`s.

Furthermore hsb values seem to be more appropriate:

- Every column has the same hue
- The first half of a column the brightness increases, but the saturation remains at 1
- the second half of the column the brightness remains at 1, but the saturation is decreased from 1 to 0

The last column is an exception since it displays only grayscale with increasing brightness.

The following code allows you to create the palette (or at least comes sufficiently close):

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.setHgap(4);
    gridPane.setVgap(4);

    final int columns = 12;
    final int rows = 10;
    final int fullBrightness = (rows - 1) / 2;
    final int columnCount = columns - 1;

    // fill upper half with full saturation but increasing brightness
    for (int y = 0; y <= fullBrightness; y++) {
        double brightness = y / (double) fullBrightness;
        for (int x = 0; x < columnCount; x++) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(15, 15, Color.hsb(x * (360d / (columns - 1)), 1, brightness));
            rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            gridPane.add(rect, x, y);
        }
    }

    // fill lower half with full brightness but decreasing saturation
    for (int y = fullBrightness + 1; y < rows; y++) {
        double saturation = 1 - ((double) (y - fullBrightness)) / (columns - 1 - fullBrightness);
        for (int x = 0; x < columnCount; x++) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(15, 15, Color.hsb(x * (360d / (columns - 1)), saturation, 1));
            rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            gridPane.add(rect, x, y);
        }
    }

    // fill last column with grayscale
    for (int y = 0, maxIndex = rows - 1; y < rows; y++) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(15, 15, Color.hsb(0, 0, y / (double) maxIndex));
        rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gridPane.add(rect, columnCount, y);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```